# From icon fonts to svg icons. How to avoid DRY code in template

Tags: svg, icons, font-awesome, glyphicons, svg-animate

I'm switching from a an older gliphycons/font-awesome icons to a modern and lighter svg font system.

My question is: I need something like this code above in every part of my website?

```
<svg class="myicon myicon-hello"><use xlink:href="assets/symbol-defs.svg#myicon-hello"></use></svg>My hello text
```

Do I really need this code in everywhere?

Is there an alternative way?

Can I load the `assets/symbol-defs.svg` just one time and then call it just using my icon name?

Answer (score 0):

You could inline the `symbol-defs.svg` file in your page, then use the simpler:

```
<svg class="myicon myicon-hello"><use xlink:href="#myicon-hello"></use></svg>My hello text
```

Comment: And this how? How I have to inline this in my SPA app?